# How do you use masks from pngs with moviepy?

Tags: python, video, mask, moviepy

I am trying to use masks with moviepy.

I would like to use an image file like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFu8H.jpg) and overlay it as a mask on top of a video, so that only the black part of the image is transparent in the video.

I am able to get this to work when I make the mask image exactly the same size as the video, but I can't figure out how to make it work with a mask image which is smaller. I would like to take the small mask image given, and position it onto the video (further I would actually like to take this mask image and put it onto a video as a mask in few different locations at once).

I've included the code below where I tried to do this as well as the error I get. Any help is appreciated (or just a link to a simple example showing how to use moviepy masks). Thank you!

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips, ImageClip, vfx, AudioFileClip, \
concatenate_audioclips, CompositeAudioClip, ColorClip, CompositeVideoClip, VideoClip

import random


if __name__ == '__main__':

    DEFAULT_CLIP_HEIGHT = 720
    DEFAULT_CLIP_WIDTH = 1280

    color_clip = ColorClip(size=(DEFAULT_CLIP_WIDTH, DEFAULT_CLIP_HEIGHT), col=((0, 0, 255)))
    color_clip = color_clip.set_duration(15)
    color_clip = color_clip.set_fps(DEFAULT_FPS)

    color_clip2 = ColorClip(size=(DEFAULT_CLIP_WIDTH, DEFAULT_CLIP_HEIGHT), col=((255, 0, 0)))
    color_clip2 = color_clip2.set_duration(15)
    color_clip2 = color_clip2.set_fps(DEFAULT_FPS)

    rounded_border_path = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'black_on_white_small.png')
    mask_clip = ImageClip(rounded_border_path)
    mask_clip = mask_clip.set_duration(10)
    mask_clip = mask_clip.set_fps(DEFAULT_FPS)
    mask_clip = mask_clip.set_position(('center', 'center'))

    comp_clip = CompositeVideoClip([mask_clip], bg_color=(255, 255, 255),
                               size=(DEFAULT_CLIP_WIDTH, DEFAULT_CLIP_HEIGHT), ismask=True)

     color_clip.mask = comp_clip

     comp_clip = CompositeVideoClip([color_clip2, color_clip], size=(DEFAULT_CLIP_WIDTH, DEFAULT_CLIP_HEIGHT))

     o_path = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'comp_color.mp4')
     comp_clip.write_videofile(o_path, fps=DEFAULT_FPS, codec='libx264')
```

yields error:
`File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/upwork_montage/custom_moviepy/moviepy/video/compositing/CompositeVideoClip.py", line 110, in make_frame
    f = c.blit_on(f, t)
  File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/upwork_montage/custom_moviepy/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 570, in blit_on
    return blit(img, picture, pos, mask=mask, ismask=self.ismask)
  File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/upwork_montage/custom_moviepy/moviepy/video/tools/drawing.py", line 43, in blit
    1.0 * mask * blitted + (1.0 - mask) * blit_region)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (720,1280,9) (720,1280,3)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a whole image (height x width x 3) as a mask. Masks in MoviePy must be (height x width x 1) with float values between 0 (transparent) and 1 (totally opaque).

Does that help ?

Comment: thanks for quick response! What is the third value in (height x width x 3) ? And how do I convert from a 'whole image' to the format the mask needs?

Comment: aaa I'm guessing the x3 means and RGB 3-tuple. So I need to convert that to a float between 0 and 1... a code example would still be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone googling this now that it's year's later, your mask image needs to be greyscale rather than full colour.

This includes the inserting of the background colour

```
bg_color=(255, 255, 255)
```

There should only be one variable, rather than the three for RGB. eg:

```
bg_color=(255)
```